# Maven fails to load dependencies on company network

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I compile a very simple maven spring boot java project in Intellij Idea on my work computer, none of the standard spring libraries in the pom.xml are pulled in. In the project view "External Libaries" only the JDK library is there with nothing from Maven

This works fine on my personal laptop through home network, so it only happens on the company laptop due to it VPN connecting to a highly secure network which requires some modification to the environment (for example the repositories and security certificates)

It works for others on the company network after minor modifications which I have also done (installing extra server certificates) which I think I did correctly but suspect maybe not despite my efforts since it's the only explanation I can think of, however visually everything appears to match a colleague's working system.

I only see my local ~/.m2 repository in the maven repository section. repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and the company git repo are missing from mine but present for others.  Even after loading the same project with the same pom.  Not sure how to get those repos to show up

How can I troubleshoot exactly what step is failing?

Comment: "It works for others on the company network after minor modifications" what are they doing to make it work? We have no way of knowing that.

Comment: (Not answering your question) you might consider install a proxy like Nexus which can cache Maven responses on your network for all maven users to fetch from.  As well as performance, this may move the configuration challenge to Nexus from each users.

Comment: I followed same steps as everybody else (so I think anyway).  involving installing server certificates

Comment: You could do a lot worse than try `mvn    compile -Djavax.net.debug=ssl`. If that's not illuminating then try a debug connection to something in each repo with something like `wget` or `curl`. But I'd probably *start* with `mvn -X compile`

Comment: Does it give you any error message when you open the Project or run Maven Lifecycles/Goals? Try starting IDEA directly from OS Command Prompt with "idea" command or specifying JAVA_HOME for Maven Importer (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_importer)

Comment: "I followed same steps as everybody else (so I think anyway). involving installing server certificates" You are not sharing enough details here of what you did or the errors. Seems related to TLS. Follow @g00se suggestion. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: The JVM running maven must know how to reach the world.  This most likely involves adding a certificate so the rewritten https chain is trusted. Strongly consider setting up an internal mirror.